# Finding a specific data and copy in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a data with 5824 elements. The values in this data set repeats with certain period. I would like to find the data with a specific value in this data set. Then I would like to copy these cells which contain the specific values, to another cells. Could you help me how to do that in Excel?

Kind regards

Comment: Can you show what your data look like (not all 5824, of course), and can you show what you have already tried? Are you looking for a formula (like based on `Match()`, `VLookup()` or others) or are you looking for a VBA macro? In case of a macro, did you already try recording and adapting one? What does it look like? ...?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the data this is difficult to answer, but let me try. There are some different methods to do this general thing.

In excel there is filters application, table filters, and the filter equation.

filter equation [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71831520/extract-data-for-same-name-aaa-and-get-relevant-different-data-in-another-shee/71832338#71832338) `=FILTER(A2:C6,B2:B6="S1")`

There are other excel equations that good for this like `=xlookup()` [video_1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0KEhR66btUs) and [video_2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pAroMUdTK6g).
Additional options are Index(,Match(,,)) and vlookup(), Sumifs(), ...etc.

Another way to do this is with the Power Query tools that are in excel. (I do recommend the Excel_on_fire videos from years 2017-2019, not linked)

1. [Get bitcoin price off the web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70908743/how-to-get-bitcoin-price-using-power-query/70908744#70908744)
2. [From another worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69679627/update-data-by-an-external-reference-link-to-a-table-in-another-workbook/69748671#69748671)
3. [Scrap the web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70089524/scrape-economic-data-from-investing-website/70089754#70089754)